# Azure web-role not starting in Azure Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I upgraded my development machine from Windows 7, VS2012 to Windows 10, VS2015.  This requires upgrading to Azure SDK 2.8.  Our web-role no longer starts.  A browser window opens and the below are last lines Debug outpu.  I have searched for a log for WaIISHost.exe to no avail.

```
The program '[2884] WaIISHost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[2884] WaIISHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[12316] w3wp.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[12316] w3wp.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: I have a similar situation after upgrading from Azure SDK 2.2 and Windows 7 to Azure 2.8 and Windows 10. Did you find a solution?

Comment: It was ultimately problems with our diagnostics configuration.  As I remember Visual Studio botched the migration and we had to go back and screw around with diagnostics in our web.config and ServiceConfigurations.Local.cscfg.

Comment: Thanks , my problem was related to the version of azure cashing library which wasn't matching my SDK version

Answer (score 0):

This might be a helpful tip for others who have a similar problem :
[Azure Cloud Service Web Role web pages do not load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562126/azure-cloud-service-web-role-web-pages-do-not-load)